# how to build react tags input with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tags

I intended to use react-tag-input, but the [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tag-input) only runs in stackblitz but in either codesandbox or my local laptop it throws DnD error "

```
(anonymous function)
node_modules/react-dnd/dist/esm/common/DndProvider.js:21
  18 |  * A React component that provides the React-DnD context
  19 |  */
  20 | 
> 21 | export var DndProvider = memo(function (_ref) {
  22 |   var children = _ref.children,
  23 |       props = _objectWithoutProperties(_ref, ["children"]);
  24 |
```

Since all I need is a tag input box without drag-n-drop functionality and ideally auto-complete using a list of high-frequency words, I then tried to use React-tag-editor. The stackblitz code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6ydcww) but it looks very different from the [demo](http://ndyag.github.io/react-tageditor/) and I don't use sass in other parts of the code. Is there any tag input package or code sample where one can add/remove tags and easily style tags with css?